# Хранение изображений и доступ к ним Android

Tags: android, массивы, изображения

Здравствуйте, такая проблема в приложении использую много image храню их в массивах типа `int[] = {r.drawable.img1,r.drawable.img2.....}`. И вроде все нормально работает, только при запуске `activity` эти массивы инициализируются и в результате сразу жрет много памяти. Может быть есть другие способы хранения и доступа к изображениям, более щадящие для памяти, что ли?

Comment: почему Вы решили, что в массиве хранятся картинки?
там хранятся ссылки типа int на ресурсы, никак не сами изображения

Comment: использовать ленивую инициализацию - подгружать картинки только когда это реально нужно.

Comment: Присоединюсь к Роману, в массиве хранятся инты, id изображений. Для их инициализации не нужно много памяти. Ищите другие утечки.

Answer (score 2):

Если до 1 метра, то можно в `assets`  и обращаться к ним примерно так  `file:///android_asset/my_file.png`   
Только придется как с файлом работать, то есть считать потоком  и дальше выводить

Comment: Что за ленивая инициализация?

Comment: значит отложенная, то есть выполняемая непосредственно перед тем как ресурсы нужно использовать

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview  + google Lazy initialization java android

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробывать

Answer (score -1):

Создаете в res/values/strings массив с именами картинок без расширений
    
    `<resources>
       <string-array name="arrayWithStrings">
        <item>comedy</item>
        <item>europa</item>
        <item>hit</item>
        <item>maximum</item>
        <item>newradio</item>
        <item>nrj</item>
        <item>radiotnt</item>
        <item>record</item>
        <item>russkyirock</item>
        <item>silverrain</item>
       </string-array>
    </resources>`
   а потом в коде вытаскиваете по этим именами id и устанавливаете в ваши image view. Например в папке drawable лежит файл comedy.png, то для него

     `String name =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrayWithStrings)[0];
     imageView.setImageResource(getResources().
                      getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName()));`

Comment: Замените картинку кодом как текст.